# Difference between two if statements + and else, and one if statement, one else if and one else?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using these statements to set progress on a progress bar, depending on the `seconds` variable. The function below is called every 1 second by a Timer object. After 7 seconds, the `refreshApp()` function is called.

```
func runTimedCode() {

    if seconds == 0 {
        self.progressView.setProgress(Float(self.seconds)/Float(7), animated: false)
        refreshApp()
        seconds += 1
    }
    else if seconds == 7 {
        self.progressView.setProgress(Float(self.seconds)/Float(7), animated: false)
        seconds = 0
    } else {
        self.progressView.setProgress(Float(self.seconds)/Float(7), animated: false)
        seconds += 1
    }
}
```

It works as it should, but when I make the second statement an `if seconds == 7 {` , instead of `else if seconds == 7`, the progress bar seems to start not from a completely empty position (jumps from completely filled at 7 seconds, to a bit filled at 1 second).

Could anyone help me understand why the behaviour changes? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you change `else if seconds == 7` into `if seconds == 7`, you will enter the first block of code **and** the third block of code when `seconds` is `0`.  If you use `else if seconds == 7`, then the whole `if` statement is done once `if seconds == 0` is satisfied.

```
let seconds = 0

if seconds == 0 {
    print("block 1")
}
else if seconds == 7 {
    print("block 2")
} else {
    print("block 3")
}
```

> ```
> block 1
> ```

```
if seconds == 0 {
    print("block 1")
}
if seconds == 7 {
    print("block 2")
} else {
    print("block 3")
}
```

> ```
> block 1
> block 3
> ```